# Return the name of files (in directory or list) whose content contains a specific pattern

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find if there are existing ways of doing this, or if I need a full-fledged script.

I have only found threads about returning true or yes for one unique file. And printing files then using `grep` destroys the information about the filenames.

Comment: Have you considered using `find -regex <pattern>`?

Comment: @steeldriver Thx a lot. That's indeed exactly what I was looking for. I am sorry for my question, I did read the manual, but searched for "filename" and the word "file" was appearing everywhere. I was a bit overwhelmed and thought I needed another command like `find` with an `-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @steeldriver, the `-l` option of `grep` is the shortest solution :

`grep -l Pattern Directory` will output every file that contains the given `Pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list you can read the list if it is a directory the you can loop through the files.

```
while read -r file; do
  grep -q PATTERN "$file" && echo "$file contains PATTERN"
done < file.txt
```

You can add as may pattern and grep invocation or use an if statement.

```
for file in ./*; do
  grep -q PATTERN "$file" && echo "$file contains PATTERN"
done
```

You can add a test so you're only grepping for files and add more grep or use an if statement inside the loop as well. That loop is not recursive you need to use shell globbing like **globstar** and probably **nullglob**. The utility **find** can do that more faster afaik. Of course those solution above requires that you're inside the directory where the files are.